# hover on image with overlay slide in effect but without any revese effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

as above code when we hover over the image it gets overlay effect but on mouse leave, I don't want this reverse effect. when mouse leave happens I just want to hide overlay and show the image as at starting.how can I achieve this.
I have tried using javascript but nothing worked for me.help me.

ref code:[link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_slidebottom)

Comment: so first time on mouse over it should overlay, and second time it should display image, right ?

Comment: yes on mouse leave i don't want any reverse effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the transition to the `hover` state

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  /* here */
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```